# Replace https links with <a> using stencil

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, stenciljs

I am facing a problem to replace the answer from api and format it properly

```
answerFromAPI = "textword textword textword textword textword.\n\nFeel free to ask me questions from this site:\nhttps://google.com  \n"
```

I want to format and render it as following:

```
textword textword textword textword textword.


Feel free to ask me questions from this site:

https://google.com     /*this should be clickable link*/
```

For that I have created two functions. 1st for textlinks

```
 let textLink = answerFromAPI.replace(/(((https?\:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+))/gi,
           function (x) {
             console.log(x)
            return '<a href="' + x + '" target="_blank">' + x + '</a>';
         })
```

2nd for new line

```
let newLine = answerFromAPI.replace(/(\n?\\n)/ig, function(n) {
            console.log(n)
            return '<br />'
          })
```

and I am trying to push into array after applying those to functions lets take testlinks for example

```
array= []
array.push(textLink)
```

after that I am rendering the array in jsx

```
render() {
let temp = []

this.array.map((a,index)=>{
temp.push(<p>{a}</p>)}
)}
```

and returning as following

```
return <div>
{temp}
</div>
```

How can I render my message properly on front end. I tried in multiple way but I am facing one issue like the response from function is passing as a string not as HTML tag.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `innerHTML` property on an element to have it render HTML and not a string.

```
return <div innerHTML={temp} />;
```

See https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx#complex-template-content for more details.

Comment: My problem is solved so I cannot implement your idea because I have to do so many changes to my existing code. May be you are correct with this solution. Anyway thank you so much man